# How Can I Loop a Cursor to use its data to update another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a table (T1) where one field contains concatenated data.
I have another table (T2) that contains the parameters to split said concatenated field in T1.
For each concatenated field (or record) in T1, there will be a n rows in T2 containing the values needed to split concatenated field (from T1).

With a primary and foreign key relationship between T1 and T2, how can I place T2 in a cursor and loop through its n rows until all its data is used to split a corresponding concatenated field in T1?

Or, maybe, I shouldn't use a cursor? I'd be most grateful for a pointer, please.

Kind regards
aHoG

Comment: Cursors should almost always be avoided. If you could post a sample of your data it would help us give you better guidance, or code you've already tried (if any).

Comment: Yes we can avoid cursor for doing this add sample data and expected result

Comment: Add sample data of T1 and T2.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Might look into [Group by with Rollup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)